# Can't store object into membased, how can I know why?

Tags: c#, winforms, memcached, couchbase, enyim

I'm trying to store an object into Cache like:

```
Dictionary<Guid, Decimal> cacheSubscribers = 
          client.Get<Dictionary<Guid, Decimal>>("ListAllSubscribers");

if (cacheSubscribers == null)
{
  cacheSubscribers = db.JK_Subscribers
                       .Where(x => x.sync)
                       .Select(x => new { x.guid, x.subscriber_id })
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.guid, x => x.subscriber_id);

  if (!client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "ListAllSubscribers", cacheSubscribers, ts))
     MessageBox.Show("Could not store ListAllSubscribers");
}
```

And I always get `client.Store` to be `false`, and it does not add to the server.

a few lines below this statement I also have:

```
IEnumerable<JK_ChallengeAnswers> challengeAnswers = client.Get<IEnumerable<JK_ChallengeAnswers>>("ListAllChallengeAnswers");
if (challengeAnswers == null)
{
    challengeAnswers = db.JK_ChallengeAnswers.Include("JK_Challenges").ToList();
    client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "ListAllChallengeAnswers", challengeAnswers, ts);
}
```

and this **always** add into memory...

> Is there a way to get the reason why I can't store the object?

`Dictionary` has around **95.000 records** and in the configuration I have

```
<socketPool minPoolSize="10" 
            maxPoolSize="100" 
            connectionTimeout="00:01:00" 
            deadTimeout="00:02:00" />
```

P.S. I'm using [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/membase-server) on `localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure because the code is not familiar..so i ask:Are you trying to store dictionary that is made of 95000 records?
Membase is very similar to memcached, so I suggest to check if there is a limit for the size of the object you can store..as I know for memcached is 1mb

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[ExecuteStore][1]` method, which returns a `IStoreOperationResult` object instead of a `bool`, where you can find a message, exceptions, etc..
It doesn't always help, but it's worth a try.

EDIT: Use Couchbase .NET Client Library **1.1** for that.